# join on mysql output

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I'm having issue with join mysql.

I have 3 tables on mysql:

```
item_extend:
list_id item_id in_id out_id quantity 
1       3       1     NULL  10      
2       4       1     NULL  30  
3       3       2     NULL  90  
4       4       2     NULL  70  


Additional_extend:
id   add_id     in_id   out_id  item_id quantity 
1       2       1       NULL    3       20
2       2       2       NULL    3       80

progress_in:
in_id   dates                progress_id
1       2014-01-13 11:36:05  1  
2       2014-01-17 10:14:13  1
```

I used this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.list_id, a.item_id, a.quantity AS x, b.add, b.quantity AS y
FROM item_extend a
JOIN additional_extend b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
JOIN progress_in d ON d.in_id = a.in_id
WHERE d.progress_id = "1"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and the result is:

## list_id     item_id                 x     add_id    y

```
1           3        10     2   20
1           3        10     2   80
3           3        90     2   20
3           3        90     2   80
```

but the expected result should be:

## list_id     item_id                 x     add_id    y

```
1           3        10     2   20
3           3        90     2   80
```

anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: There are no duplicate records in the result. If you compare all columns then last column has different values (20 & 80 are different in the first two rows).

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: You could `GROUP BY a.list_id`...not sure if that's what you're looking for though.

Comment: ok, I think my questions must be revised..

Comment: I added syntax AND a.in_id = b.in_id, it works but for records where both items_extend and additional_extend are related. I want to show all records unless are related or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple `quantity` values for one `item_id` in the `additional_extend` table which is why you are getting multiple rows in the output. Since there are more than one `quantity` values, you will have to aggregate the `quantity` column of `additional_extend` table for each `items_id`, like this:

```
SELECT a.list_id, a.item_id, a.quantity AS x, b.add_id, SUM(b.quantity) AS y
FROM item_extend a
JOIN additional_extend b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
JOIN progress_in d ON d.in_id = a.in_id
WHERE d.progress_id = 1
GROUP BY a.list_id, a.item_id, x, b.add_id
```

Comment: yes it worked, but I found the better answer in my case, use JOIN additional_extend b ON (a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.in_id = b.in_id). anyway, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use GROUP BY because your orginal query shows multiple times same id

Comment: its not effective though for more records.